# How to insert template in php file

Tags: php, templates

I 've used the following code to create PHP file dynamically

```
$value = 5;
$file = $compname.'.php';
$file_pointer = fopen( $file, 'w' );
$string = '<?php $var = '. $value .' ?>';
fwrite( $file_pointer, $string );
fclose($file_pointer);
include($file);
echo $var;
```

Is it possible to insert template in that php file and the file name conatins spaces is it possible to remove those space and add "-"

Comment: ... What is this I don't even... Are you mass-producing PHP files to hold a single variable each? Also, what do you mean by "insert template"?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want to achieve? Someone here might give you a better work around instead of writing files for a single variable.

Comment: would you be better to save some values in a database based on the $compname, rather than creating configuration files? if not then you could create a template like <?php $var='#var#'; ?> then file(../template.php) then str_replace #var# with the $value before writing it back out again to $compname.php BUT this could be security risk as people could inject php code into your system

Comment: @Waygood, he doesnt need to do the `str_replace` you mention. If he has template.php that is `echo 'hello'.$name;` he can just make a new file and do `$name='xx';include('template.php')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ianhales mentioned, you can use str_replace() for replacing white-spaces in the name. If I understand your question correctly, you want to use a template file to generate the contents of the PHP file. To do that, I would do the following.

Create template.txt file

```
<?php
 $var = #THEVAR#;
?>
```

Then you use the template:

```
<?php
 ...
 $value = 5;
 $template = file_get_contents('template.txt');
 $template = str_replace("#THEVAR#", $value, $template);
 $newFile = fopen($compname.'.php', 'w');
 fwrite($newFile, $template);
 fclose($newFile);
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

[str_replace( )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) will do your ' ' to '-' replacement. The rest of your question I don't understand.

Comment: Is that even necessary? The filename is (from the looks of it) dynamically generated by the OP anyway. A better question is: why is the OP asking how to change a name that he dynamically generated?

Comment: That seems fair, but I assumed the OP had their reasons. That said, it does seem odd to create your own problem!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to have a pre made PHP file and change some stuff there?

You can use placeholders, for instance.

example
PHP FILE

```
<?php
$var = '[%%VAR1%%]';
?>
```

file editor:

```
//Change filename
str_replace(' ', '-', $compname);

//File "template editor"   
$value = 5;
$file = file_get_contents($compname.'.php');
str_replace('[%%VAR1%%]',$value, $file);
file_put_contents($compname.'.php', $file);
```

Comment: edit file_get_contents() to open the template.php file instead.

Comment: OP can I set $value to '; print_r(get_defined_vars()); echo '

Comment: OP can I also have my company name as index or whatever your script is called or the template filename???

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention if you want your template file to be PHP parsed first. This method could do (or not):

```
function getTemplateContent($includeFile, $parsePhp = TRUE) {
$cont = '';
if ($parsePhp) {
    try {
        ob_start();
        require($includeFile);
        $cont = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $cont = '';
    }
} else {
    $cont = file_get_contents($includeFile); #
}
return $cont;
}
```

To include the template contents in the written file could be done like e.g.

```
$string = '<?php $var = '. $value . ';' . getTemplateContent($templateFile, TRUE/FALSE) . ' ?>'
```